# LyX: Can't compile with \usepackage{algpseudocode} with Language that isn't English

Tags: lyx, hebrew, algorithmic

I'm pretty new to LyX and Latex.

I'm writing a paper in Hebrew and I want to add an algorithm in English.

So I'm adding `\usepackage{algpseudocode}` to the Preamble and pasting some example algorithm. When the document language is English - everything works as expected - but when I change it to Hebrew it generates tons of errors.

This is the source code:

THIS works:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.1.4 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}
\Procedure{CrossValidate}{$\Phi$}
\ForAll{$\phi \in {\Phi_1,\cdots,\Phi_{k-1},\Phi_k}$}
\State $model =$ Train($\Phi \setminus \phi$ )
\ForAll{$s \in \phi$ }
\State \Comment{hej}
\EndFor
\EndFor   
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

THIS doesn't:

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.1.4 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9,cp1255]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}%
\inputencoding{latin9}\begin{algorithmic}
\Procedure{CrossValidate}{$\Phi$}
\ForAll{$\phi \in {\Phi_1,\cdots,\Phi_{k-1},\Phi_k}$}
\State $model =$ Train($\Phi \setminus \phi$ )
\ForAll{$s \in \phi$ }
\State \Comment{hej}
\EndFor
\EndFor   
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}\selectlanguage{hebrew}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: does this also happen when you use algorithm2e ?

Answer (score 1):

The `algorithmicx` package use the printed version of a counter (i.e `\thefoo` for the counter `foo`) rather than the counter itself in places where it shouldn't, such as between `\csname ... \endcsname` or in fonditionals involving `\ifnum`.

Since hindu arabic numerals should be printed left to right, even in right to left context, `babel-hebrew` patches the way numbers are printed, and this is the source of the problem.

You can make a local copy the code of the `algorithmicx` package (under a different name), and change  in some places `thefoo` to `\number\c@foo`.

you can patch how `babel-hebrew` treats hindu arabic numerals by adding the line `\def\@arabic#1{\if@rl\@number{\@@arabic#1}\else\number#1\fi}` after `\usepackage{babel}` (or in the preamble of LyX add the line `\AddToHook{package/babel/after}{\def\@arabic#1{\if@rl\@number{\@@arabic#1}\else\number#1\fi}}` if `babel` is loaded after the preamble). It will fix the problem with the `\csname` construct, but conditionals will still fail. I don't think there is a smart way to go around that, but fortunately `algorithmicx` use only one problematic conditional at the `enddocument` hook. Replace the code on the hook with the following

```
\AddToHook{enddocument}{%
\ifnum\number\c@ALG@storecount>0\relax
      \PackageError{algorithmicx}{Some stored algorithms are not restored!}{}%
   \fi
}
```

Here is how to fix your mwe

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.1.4 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9,cp1255]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\AddToHook{package/babel/after}{\def\@arabic#1{\if@rl\@number{\@@arabic#1}\else\number#1\fi}}
\RemoveFromHook{enddocument}[algorithmicx]
\AddToHook{enddocument}{%
\ifnum\number\c@ALG@storecount>0\relax
      \PackageError{algorithmicx}{Some stored algorithms are not restored!}{}%
   \fi
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{english}%
\inputencoding{latin9}\begin{algorithmic}
\Procedure{CrossValidate}{$\Phi$}
\ForAll{$\phi \in {\Phi_1,\cdots,\Phi_{k-1},\Phi_k}$}
\State $model =$ Train($\Phi \setminus \phi$ )
\ForAll{$s \in \phi$ }
\State \Comment{hej}
\EndFor
\EndFor   
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}\selectlanguage{hebrew}%

\end{document}
```

[image]